# php file only works after reload

Tags: php

I use this script to create a mysqpl dump and then upload the file to dropbox. If i run the script at first nothing happens -> blank page. But when i refresh the page everything works fine

```
    <?php

######## einstellungen #############################################

$db_name = "name";
$db_passwd = "pw";

$sql_file = "dump_" . $db_name . "_" . date('Ymd_Hi') . ".sql";

#################################################################### 

exec("mysqldump -u $db_name -p'$db_passwd' --allow-keywords --add-drop-table --complete-insert --quote-names $db_name > $sql_file"); 
exec("gzip $sql_file");

$datei = $sql_file . ".gz";
$link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link = str_replace(basename(__FILE__),$datei,$link);


require 'DropboxUploader.php';
while (!file_exists($datei)) sleep(1);




$uploader = new DropboxUploader('email', 'pw');
$uploader->upload($datei);



?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the `while` loop. Calling `sleep(1)` won't create the file if it doesn't exist. You're not doing anything in the background to create the file.

Comment: The script doesn't produce any output. Why do you think you should get something other than a blank page?

Comment: @Barmar he's probably meaning that the refresh makes the upload work.

Comment: If i run the script by entering its url nothing happens until i refresh that page. 

i added the while loop because creating the file had some delay and it tried to upload a file that did not exist. The loop makes the script wait until the file is created and then uploads it

Comment: `while (!file_exists($datei)) sleep(1);` is not needed as the two `exec`s that generate the file (dump+gzip) are executed syncronously. If then you don't have the file an error occurred. Also please clarify your question as the script is not intended to produce output in any case.

Comment: The problem is if i don't use the loop, the files are not uploaded to dropbox. I think is because it takes some time for the files to exist and it tries to upload them before they exist

Comment: The documentation of DropboxUploader.php recommends using Dropbox's API now that it exists. Have you tried that to see if it works better?

Comment: @Barmar I tried but couldn't get the Dropbox API to work. I followed the tutorial on their website but it would not get me an access token. That's why i used dropboxuploader.php instead of the API